# HTML video not playing with Vue.js 2

Tags: html, video, vue.js

I have an HTML video in my web app:

```
<video src="" id="video-container" controls></video>
```

Initially the source is empty and I change it dynamically with JS, after loading some data:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video-container');
...
video.src = VIDEO_URL;
video.play();
```

That used to work perfectly and it was compatible with Vue.js 1 but, since I migrated to Vue.js 2 the video is no longer working. Calls to video.play(), video.pause() have no effect on the video player and attributes such as video.clientWidth returns zero values.

Is there any incompatibility with this element in Vue.js 2? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible to create a fiddle of this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

While I was creating the fiddle as saurabh suggested I found the 'solution' (even if I can not provide an accurate explanation).

The problem arises when we are using VueJS 2 and we define the video element var before instantiating the Vue class. Strangely, the same code is working with VueJS 1:

[Video not working. Vue 2.1.3](https://jsfiddle.net/6qmjw5xd/)

[Video working. Vue 1.0.28](https://jsfiddle.net/L6pgvj5w/)

```
var video = document.getElementById('video-container');

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
});

video.src = "http://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player/video/tears-of-steel-battle-clip-medium.mp4";
video.play();
```

If the var is defined after Vue instantiation, everything works with version 2.

jsfiddle.net/6qmjw5xd/1/

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});

var video = document.getElementById('video-container');

video.src = "http://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player/video/tears-of-steel-battle-clip-medium.mp4";
video.play();
```

Answer (score 18):

### Edit: Please check out [Chrome's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted) on force playing a video before implementing this.

Now that I know more about VueJS, this solution seems much better:

[jsfiddle working](https://jsfiddle.net/6qmjw5xd/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <video ref="videoRef" src="" id="video-container" width="100%" controls></video>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted: function() {
    this.$refs.videoRef.src = "http://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player/video/tears-of-steel-battle-clip-medium.mp4";
    this.$refs.videoRef.play();
  }
});
```